# adding missing double quotes in file

Tags: java, string, file, csv

I have a file which contains double quotes only to String types but i need to add missing double quotes to other fields and write into a file using java.

for example

```
123  ,6   ,"abc@yahoo.com"
                                            "
```

should be converted to

```
"123  ","6   ","abc@yahoo.com"                                         "
```

without trimming any value just adding the missing text qualifier around the fields. I have tried by splitting based on delimiter and then wrapping around quotes but it did not work.

please share if you have solved any issue like this.

Comment: i think you forget to add double quotes at the last.

Comment: Use `replaceAll` method with a regex.

Comment: Show what you have tried, explain what you mean by "it did not work".

Comment: by replacing all quotes by empty and then splitting line based on delimiter and finally wrapping quotes. getting issue if string has delimiter in between quotes

Comment: @imroze527 is `,"abc@yahoo.com ` your input? What about the missing quotes at the last?

Comment: @avinash nope this is the input 123  ,6   ,"abc@yahoo.com                                                 "

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `string.replaceAll` method.

```
string.replaceAll("(^|,)(?!\")([^,]+)", "$1\"$2\"");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uR1mF4/1)

Comment: it is failing if we have "," in between string

Comment: you the one said that the comma is the delimiter. If not, then which is the actual delimiter?

Comment: @yes comma is delimiter. what if a string contain comma in middle? like "abc,def"

Answer (score 1):

There's a solution without such a complicated regular expressions: you have to split your input by `,` and wrap the resulting `String`s:

```
String[] splitted = input.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < splitted.size(); ++i) {
    if (splitted[i].charAt(0) != '"') {
        splitted[i] = "\"" + splitted[i] + "\"";
    }
}
String output = String.join(",", Arrays.asList(splitted)); // or any other joining technic, this is from Java 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using split() method from String class and just add quote when you need it.
Basically, I would try something like this:

```
public static void main (String... args) {
    String st = "123  ,6   ,\"abc@yahoo.com";
    String[] results = st.split(",");
    String result = "";

    for (String s : results) {
        if (!s.startsWith("\""))
            s = "\"" + s + "\"";
        if (!s.endsWith("\""))
            s+="\"";

        s+=",";

        result += s;
    }

    System.out.println(st);
    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This keep spaces and add some missing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and the below is working...

```
public static void test()
{
    String str = "123  ,6   ,\"abc@yahoo.com                                                 \"";
    String result = "",temp="";
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str,",");
    while(token.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        temp = token.nextToken();
        if(!temp.startsWith("\""))
            result += "\""+temp+"\"";
        else
            result += temp;
    }
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Please check...

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple foreach and if loop to check if the value has double quotes then add quotes to the values.

```
for(Object obj:YourContainer){    
   if(!value.contains("\"")){
        String s = "\"" + value + "\"";
    }
}
```

If you are getting fields like `""Test""` with double double quotes, try using the replace function.

```
String s;
for(Object obj:YourContainer){    
   if(!value.contains("\"")){
        s = "\"" + value + "\"";
    }
    s = s.replace("\"\"","\"");
}
```